# Stripe Webhooks Pending Status Test webhook error: 500

Tags: stripe-payments

I got Test webhook error: 500 Error in Response? Why?

How to resolve the problem? What is 500 error Status mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With code 500 it is Internal Server error. So looks like the issue is on the server side.

Please see the various status codes for your reference, this will help you with debugging web requests.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html